# Interference of two phase-modulated photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-electrodynamics, interference

Results about the quantum mechanical formulation of **single-photon** Mach-Zehnder set-up are already accessible.
However, it is not obvious how two photons interfere when we have applied an arbitrary phase on each of them.

For a more realistic mind-picture, in the same Mach-Zehnder experiment, how do we quantum mechanically formulate the interference of **two photons** each of which has passed one of the arms of the interferometer and on each of which we have imposed an arbitrary phase using a phase-shifter.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: There can be no phases for individual photons, as their wave nature is in the probability distribution given by the $Ψ^*Ψ$ where  $Ψ$ is the quantum mechanical wavefunction for the photon in the  particular boundary conditions.  An individual  photon has only spin (+1 or -1 to direction of motion), energy and momentum and mass zero.

Comment: unless what you call "photons" are the "photons" of quantum optics, which is a different  QFT than the standard mode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model l QFT.